# How can I get Excel to programmatically write to CSV?

Tags: vba, excel

At the moment my spreadsheet reads financial data.  I would like to programmatically dump this to CSV every second.  How can I do this in VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Sub SetTimeout()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:30"), "SaveAsCSV"
End Sub

Sub SaveAsCSV()
    Calculate
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="book1.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    Call SetTimeout
End Sub
```

Just call `SetTimeout()` whenever you want to start saving and it will do so every 30 seconds from then on (hence the `Now + TimeValue("00:00:30")` part)